# Windows Store Apps C# & XAML - how to animate stackpanel fading in from right to left

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8, fadein

You know, when we open "People", "Calendar", "Mail", and any other pre-installed apps in Windows 8, everything fill fade in from right to left to their original position.  How do we do this?

I have tried FadeIn codes from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.fadeoutthemeanimation.aspx

Like its name, it makes my stack panel fade in, but not as I expected it would come from right to left.

I have also tried DoublaAnimation codes from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation(v=vs.95).aspx

not so much different than FadeIn an FadeOut.

So how do we simply fade in from right to left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about the `Page` animations, you effectively add them to your elements and the OS will take care of the rest.

You were on the right track with the FadeIn animations, but you need a `Page` transition.

check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452701.aspx#page_transition and give it a try

Comment: Sure, just create a new instance of the `EntranceThemeTransition` and add it to the `ChildrenTransitions` property of your element/control/page